# Como muestro un valor de la BD en un <select> que esta cargado con paises?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un select que cargo con los paises, y de mySQL recupero un valor. Primero cargo todo el select, pero después cómo hago que en el select me muestre el país seleccionado que viene de la bd ? Se entiende que en la BD almaceno el "paiscod"

```
<select id="pais" class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="pais">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php
       $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");
       while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       ?>
       <option value = "<?php echo $valores['paiscod']?>"><?php echo ($valores['paisnom'])?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Así cargo el select

Comment: con que estas trabajando javascript o jquery y que has intentado?

Comment: hasta ahora resolvía otros casos de select con php if($values == "3") { ?>
            <option value="3" selected>Capacitador</option>
          <?php } else{ ?>
            <option value="3">Capacitador</option>
          <?php }      pero son selects chiquitos con 2 o como maximo 4 opciones...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes comparar el valor de `$valores['paiscod']` con la variable `$codPais` (contiene el id que debe estar seleccionado) y si son iguales agregar el atributo `selected` a la etiqueta `<option>`.

```
<select id="pais" class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="pais">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php
       $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT paiscod, paisnom FROM paises ORDER BY paisnom");

       while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
           if ( $valores['paiscod'] == $codPais ) { 
    ?>
       <option value = "<?php echo $valores['paiscod']?>" selected><?php echo ($valores['paisnom'])?></option>
    <?php
        } else {
    ?>
       <option value = "<?php echo $valores['paiscod']?>"><?php echo ($valores['paisnom'])?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```